# A quick question about replacement in string in C#

Tags: c#

I have a string "a ; b; c d;   e"

How can I remove the white space around ";" but keep the one between chars. So after replacement, I want to get "a;b;c d;e"

Thanks

Comment: Split(";"c) your String and then remove the outer spaces with trim. Use a StringBuilder to concat the items together again.

Comment: @Time Schmelter, why use a StringBuilder when we have string.Join

Comment: @Tim Schmelter - You should probably post your answer as an actual answer so the questioner can accept it. Yours is clearly the best solution, in my opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would work if you only had one space before or after the `;`

```
var clean = "a ; b; c d; e".Replace(" ;", ";").Replace("; ", ";");
```

If there could be multiple spaces before or after the `;`, you could run it in a loop that's exit condition was when neither `" ;"` or `"; "` was found

Alternatively, a regex would work perfectly for this.

Comment: Then what about if there is possiblly more than 1 whitespace around ";"

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression.

I've added code

```
function stripSpacesKeepSemicolons(string dirty) {
    private static Regex keepSemicolonStripSpacesRegex = new Regex("\\s*(;)\\s*");
    return keepSemicolonStripSpacesRegex.Replace(dirty,"$1");
}
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this because a Regex IS suited for this, there are just many Regex haters out there

Comment: This isn't very useful without at least a basic example or a link for more information. I could just as easily say "use the string BCL methods" but this probably wouldn't help the asker very much.

Comment: There should at least the Regex mentioned in the answer.
I could ever say use the magic and it works ;)

Comment: Indeed, then just comment that he should provide it.  Don't downvote with adding a CONSTRUCTIVE comment

Comment: I haven't downvote it. But i can understand that others have.

Comment: I added a function using a regex for Xint0

Comment: RegEx's are awesome tools, but it's overkill in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

```
string source = "a ; b; c d; e";
string result = source.Replace(" ;", ";").Replace("; ", ";");
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for any number of spaces around the semi-colon:

```
var str = "a ; b; c d; e";
while (str.IndexOf("; ") > -1 || str.IndexOf(" ;") > -1) {
  str = str.Replace("; ", ";").Replace(" ;", ";");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
  string s = "a ; b; c d; e";
  string x = String.Join(";", s.Split(';').Select(t => t.Trim()));
```

This should work regardless of the number of spaces involved.